# res.redirect causes error in .catch statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, promise

I am using Node.js and have a database call being performed with a promise.  I setup a '.then/.catch' to handle the result of the promise.  That part all seems to work without any issue.  After I do some processing of the data returned from the database I am attempting to 'redirect' to another route within the '.then' statement.  This re-direction seems to be causing a problem with the '.catch' statement.  I have no error issues if I remove the 'res.redirect'...is there a workaround?  Any suggestions appreciated.

code:

```
const db = require('./routes/queries'); 

//**Query PostGres database...

db.getMembers()
.then(function(value) {
console.log('Async success!', value);

//do some processing on the data returned from the promise call here...

//if I insert a redirect here...such as "res.redirect('/_members');"...
//I get a "Caught an error! ReferenceError: res is not defined" message...?
//evidently the redirect fires the '.catch' statement below...why?

})
.catch(function(err) {
console.log('Caught an error!', err);
});
```

Comment: Well, the error message seems pretty clear. Where are you defining `res`?

Comment: I am using Node.js with Express...I have a number of res.redirect statements within the code, and none cause any problem...only this within my promise resolve statement...'res.redirect' is part of standard Express functionality.  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Can you show more context here? More specifically where res comes from and what happens to it? It may have to do with the asynchronicity? res losing scope? Idk, like I said, we'd have to see the full context to be able to tell.

Comment: the redirection to another route seems to throw the '.catch' statement...is there no way to redirect page navigation within the '.then'...?

Comment: Then I can only assume that this code lives outside of a request handler where `res` is not defined. `res` is not a magical variable that just exists. *You* are declaring it when you define a request event handler (e.g. `api.get('/foo', function (req, res) { ... })`). You are responsible for passing it to where it's needed.

Comment: Not sure what to give you other than Express standard documentation reference here:  https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect

Comment: @Pangit I *highly* doubt it has anything to do with the redirect or catch statement. The error message pretty clearly states that within the calling context, `res` is not defined

Comment: @Pangit `res` is not a global variable..? It's got to be defined in some route handler callback somewhere. Please post that code

Comment: if it is not related to the '.catch' statement then why is the console message within the '.catch' statement being displayed ('caught an error!')...obviously it is being fired by the redirect...since it does not occur when the redirect is removed

Comment: @Pangit Because accessing the `redirect` method on a variable `res` that is not defined is an unhandled exception in javascript. Hence why it's triggering your `.catch()` handler. You would see the same error if you substituted `foo.bar()` instead of `res.redirect()` in your code.

Comment: then how to I define 'res'...?  It is standard Express functionality...I have them throughout my code without any other issues.

Comment: @Pangit See Felix Kling's comment above. It's not a magical variable that just exists when you import the express dependency. It's passed through on the callback for route handlers for individual requests.

Comment: OK...so I need to add something like:  "app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.redirect('GET request to another page')
})"    ....correct???

Comment: yes you should. Or you can pass your function the res object

Comment: OK thanks to all that replied...I will give that a try and see what I can see...

Comment: @Pangit Yeah, and that function would wrap your database call that you have in your post as well. Should look like the following: `app.get("/", function (req, res) { db.call().then(function () { ... do stuff, res.redirect() if success }).catch(function () { ...catch err, res.end() or res.send(), or a different redirect here })});`

Comment: Thanks to all that posted information...I seem to have functionality more as I intended now.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend providing a reusable promise in case you need to find your members list elsewhere in your Express app

```
const db = require('./routes/queries'); 

const findMembers = () => {
    return db.getMembers()
            .then(members => {
                 return members
            })
            .catch(err => {
                 console.log('Caught an error!', err);
            }); 
}


//inside your express app 

app.get("/some_route", (req, res) => {
   return findMembers()
     .then(members => {
        //do something with your members list
       res.redirect("/redirect_route")
     })
})
```

Comment: @Pangit Thanks for the edit request. Are you sure that the reason you are seeing [Object, object] in the console.log is due to the promise issue? I think its because you are trying to console.log an object as a string instead of console.log(members)